Device does not appear in DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;

/* ... */

var deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher();
deviceWatcher.Added += async (watcher, deviceInfo) => {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(deviceInfo.Name);
};
deviceWatcher.Start();

Using this I do not see my BLE device, but it does appear in Windows 10's "Add Bluetooth or other device" menu. What could be wrong in my usage of the watcher ?
Edit : After investigation, this code works on .net 4 but not on .net 8 and I have no idea why.

Okay so at least from .net 8, the API has changed and you need this to make it work :
System.Devices.Aep reference
deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher("(System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{bb7bb05e-5972-42b5-94fc-76eaa7084d49}\")", null, DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpoint);
The GUID is the BLE one, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/enumerate-devices-over-a-network

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. Can you [edit] your answer to summarize the relevant guidance from the link? Answers on Stack Overflow can certainly link to additional information, but they should stand on their own even if the page they are linking to is later (re)moved. This is important because often, over time, the linked pages are no longer available, which is frustrating for future members of the community.
